# Is it possible to suppress the column header in the cqlsh output?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I want one of my several SELECT statements to not print the column headers, just the selected records. Is this possible in Cassandra 3.0?

I tried the below but it returns the column name:

```
cqlsh -e "select count(1) from system_schema.keyspaces where keyspace_name='test'";
 count
-------
     1
```

MySQL has options like -s -N to suppress the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built-in option in `cqlsh` that would allow you to suppress the output header from CQL `SELECT`.

Your best option is to use shell scripting to parse the output. There are several Linux utilities available you can use depending on the outcome you're after. Here are just some examples in a long list of possibilities:

EXAMPLE 1 - To print the first row of results (4th line of the cqlsh output), you can use the `awk` utility:

```
$ cqlsh -e "SELECT ... FROM ..." | awk 'NR==4'
```

EXAMPLE 2 - The `sed` utility equivalent is:

```
$ cqlsh -e "SELECT ... FROM ..." | sed -n '4p'
```

EXAMPLE 3 - If you want to print all the rows, not just the first (assuming your query returns multiple rows):

```
$ cqlsh -e "SELECT ... FROM ..." | tail -n +4 | head -n -2
```

The `tail -n +4` will print all lines from the 4th onwards and `head -n -2` will strip out the last 2 lines (blank line + `(# rows)` at the end). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Try this option as workaround:

```
# cqlsh -e "select count(1) from system_schema.keyspaces where keyspace_name='test'" | tail -n +4
     0

(1 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

@Dexter, for selecting records, why can't you simply leverage `SELECT * FROM system_schema.keyspaces where keyspace_name='test';`?

What are you trying to achieve here, i.e. the end result?

If you simply want to count the number of records, you could simply leverage DataStax Bulk Loader to perform the count operation.

References:

- https://www.datastax.com/blog/datastax-bulk-loader-counting
- https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/docs/dsbulkAbout.html

```
./dsbulk count -k system_schema -t keyspaces
```

Alternatively, you could leverage the `dsbulk unload -query <...>` to selectively unload records based on the query that you pass in.